# Audio porting to apple sillicon, when using google speech to text

Tags: swift, macos, core-audio, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am using google speech to text for my Mac OS X application. In all Mac OS below 11.0, its working fine. but in Apple Sillicon Mac, when I start Google Speech to Text, it generates some noise in speakers. I read in apple site that we need to port Audio Code for Apple Sillicon. In my code AudioBufferList is using Core Audio, which has to be migrated to some other which doesnt use core audio family.

```
var callbackStruct = AURenderCallbackStruct()
callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = nil//UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(inputUnit,//neh - remoteIOUnit
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              bus1,
                              &callbackStruct,
                              UInt32(MemoryLayout<AURenderCallbackStruct>.size));
if (status != noErr) {
  return status
}


func recordingCallback(
  inRefCon:UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
  ioActionFlags:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
  inTimeStamp:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
  inBusNumber:UInt32,
  inNumberFrames:UInt32,
  ioData:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus {

  var status = noErr

  let channelCount : UInt32 = 1

  var bufferList = AudioBufferList()
  bufferList.mNumberBuffers = channelCount
    
  let buffers = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &bufferList.mBuffers, count: Int(bufferList.mNumberBuffers))
  buffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1
  buffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2
  buffers[0].mData = nil
    
  // get the recorded samples
  status = AudioUnitRender(AudioController.sharedInstance.audioEngine.inputNode.audioUnit!,//neh - remoteIOUnit
                           ioActionFlags,
                           inTimeStamp,
                           inBusNumber,
                           inNumberFrames,
                           UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>(&bufferList))
    
  if (status != noErr) {
    return status;
  }

  let data = Data(bytes:  buffers[0].mData!, count: Int(buffers[0].mDataByteSize))
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    AudioController.sharedInstance.delegate.processSampleData(data)
  }

  return noErr
}
```

So my question is what is equivalent to this code? which generates audio buffer from the live audio recording?

Comment: Swift is not realtime safe and should not be used in a `AURenderCallbackStruct`. This may or may not be the problem.

Comment: Bt it works perfectly in other all Mac device accept M1 sillicon.

Comment: True, but you are violating the realtime rules which can give glitchy audio. Why not try rewriting the render callback in c?